Sitecore related items failure
I have a Sitecore 10.2 site. While publishing the related items I sometimes see the following error. This occurs when there is a broken reference on the item.  Is there a way to configure this to skip the broken reference?  Failing the publish without any useful information to the content author is not helpful.
I have published the related items configured for Publishing.DeepScanRelatedItems = false.
Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Data.SitecoreContentTestStore.GetTestVariableID(RenderingReference reference)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Data.SitecoreContentTestStore.GetMultivariateTestVariable(RenderingReference reference, Language language)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.XConnect.Integration.Services.ContentTestingService.GetDatasources(RenderingReference rendering, Language language)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.AddRenderingDataSourceReferences(Item item, PublishOptions options)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.GetReferencedItems(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.GetItemReferences(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.GetItemReferencesProcessor.Process(PublishItemContext context)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.GetItemReferencesPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context, List`1& referrers, List`1& children)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext context)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)

I have reviewed the Sitecore documentation and logs and have not found any solution to my problem.

This was a known issue with Sitecore version 9 and there was a hotfix for it released by the Sitecore Support team.
You are on version 10.2, so the previously experienced problem should be resolved there. If you have some invalid renderings on the pages you are trying to publish then it could result into a similar issue. Could you please go to the Presentation tab -> Details -> Controls -> Edit and see if you have any invalid controls on the concerned pages? They will be shown as "unknown rendering". If there are some then please delete them and try re-publishing again.

I haven't found any unknown renderings.  I did isolate a couple of page items causing problems.  One had a broken link, fixing the broken link allowed the page to publish.  The second page was odd.  I isolated the rendering that was causing the issue.  I removed the data source and the page published correctly.  I investigated the data source and it was a valid path to a valid item. I restored the data source to the rendering and still the page published correctly.
